# Property using Generics in Delphi

Tags: delphi, generics, properties

I'm trying to write a property which uses generics:

```
type TMyClass = class
  protected
    function GetCountBy<T: Class>: Integer;
  public
    property CountBy<T: Class>: Integer read GetCountBy<T>;
  end;
```

but the compile fails on the property declaration with the message 'Property CountBy does not exist in base class', and the red squiggle on the opening < of the property name.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Edit:
Here's my other use case, which is more complex but more real world:

```
property ItemsBy<T: Class>[Index: Integer]: T read GetItemsBy<T> write SetItemsBy<T>;
```

The function filters the contents of a list to return the Index'th item of the specified class.

Comment: You simply need TDictionary<TClass, Integer> here. Generics are not appropriate to this problem.

Comment: -1. This would be a better question if it were motivated by a problem that would actually benefit from generics. The example "generic property" in the question doesn't need generics at all. This has the potential to be a fine question asking about the right syntax for generic properties (if such syntax even exists), but the example problem to be solved by such syntax doesn't really demonstrate the need.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generic properties are not supported in Delphi. Only generic classes, or generic methods.

I can't find anything in the documentation that explicitly states that limitation. On the other hand the documentation only describes generic classes and generic methods. And the [new language grammar to support generics](https://web.archive.org/web/20110210122056/http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Changes_in_Standard_Functions_and_Grammar) also makes no mention of properties.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not up to speed on generics but shouldn't the declaration be more like this

```
  type TMyClass<T: class> = class
  protected
    function GetCountBy<T>: Integer;
  public
    property CountBy<T>: Integer read GetCountBy<T>;
  end;
```

Comment: @Lieveb, the class contains a list of objects. I want a property to return a count of objects of a given class, so I don't need to class itself to 'genericalised', only the Countby property. (I can do this with a function, but I'd rather implement as a property).

Comment: @MikeSutton - Why would you use generics at all for that? Can't you just declare your property as `property CountBy[AClass: TClass]: Integer read GetCountBy;`

Comment: @Lieven: no, not necessarily. A normal class can have generic methods. But I don't think generic properties are allowed this way. The only solution is to make the class generic and the property NOT generic.

Comment: @Lieven my next use case is an ItemsBy<T> property where this model would be more appropriate. For now I've implemented both as functions which is neater to my eyes than your suggestion.

Comment: @Mike Why do you think compile time generics are a better fit than run time parameters? It looks to me like you simply think <> looks better. That's a completely bogus motivation. Use a function and pass a parameter. It's cleaner and more flexible.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I want the ItemsBy<T> property to return an object of class T which I can use without casting. I don't see any other way to do this than with generics. (See updated question).

Comment: Well, if you completely change the question, then the answer could be different.